# How do I pass a redirect URL for Google's Client Python Library for Oauth2?

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm trying to follow this documentation - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

I use this function to create the auth url `step1_get_authorize_url()` which works fine.  I've written the callback handler successfully and created the credentials object.

How I do I redirect to a continue url to get back to the original page now the credentials have been created.

I don't see how to pass this parameter in `step1_get_authorize_url()` which would seem to make sense.

Step 1 /url-1 creates login link, /oauth2callbackhandler receives the code and creates the credential object; how do I redirect back to /url-1?

Answer (score 0):

I found it was possible through the `state` parameter of the Flow object.

```
    state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
              for x in xrange(32))
    flow.params['state'] = 'security_token%3D' + state + '%26url%3D' + urllib.quote_plus(self.request.url)
```

I store the security token in the session to verify it.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0):

`step1_get_authorize_url()` is a method of a flow object and that flow object holds the redirect URL and gets it passed at creation.

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        secrets_file,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

A fully working example and explanations you will find [here](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/oauth2-google-api-python-google-analytics/). The tutorial features a console app but the process is analoguous to what you need to do in case of a web application.